# Get the multiple selected checkbox values from listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

In my windows phone application I am getting all contacts and attach checkbox with each like below:

```
xaml page
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <ListBox x:Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="293" Margin="24,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Name="contactChk" IsChecked="false" Foreground="Black" Background="Black" BorderBrush="White"></CheckBox>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btn_addContacts"
                    Content="Add"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Foreground="Blue"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    Click="btn_addContacts_Click" Margin="130,496,126,-89"></Button>

        </Grid>
```

and below is the xaml.cs page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class SelectionOfContacts : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        List<CustomContact> listOfContact = new List<CustomContact>();
        public SelectionOfContacts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Contacts cons = new Contacts();
            cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);
            cons.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
        }
        private void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //List<CustomContact> listOfContact = new List<CustomContact>();
                foreach (var c in e.Results)
                {
                    CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();
                    contact.Name = c.DisplayName;
                    int count = c.PhoneNumbers.Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        if (count > 0 && c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber))
                        {
                            contact.Number[i] = c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contact.Number[i] = "";
                        }
                    }
                    listOfContact.Add(contact);

                }

                ContactResultsData.ItemsSource = listOfContact;

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                //No results
            }
            if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
            }
            else
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
            }
        }

        private void btn_addContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectvalue = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

And its working fine and at this line `var selectvalue = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem` get me only only selected value of checkbox but I want to get the multiple selected checkbox values from listbox, kindly suggest me, what I do, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox.selecteditems) (with an 's' at the end) property? According to the documentation ListBoxes have that, and it seems exactly what you are looking for.

You may have to modify the SelectionMode property of the ListBox.

> When SelectionMode is Multiple or Extended, use the SelectedItems
>   property to get the items that are selected. When SelectionMode is
>   Single, use the Selector.SelectedItem property to get the item that's
>   selected.

Also, you should set up a Binding for the CheckBoxes in your ItemTemplate to make it work:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContactResultsData" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="293" Margin="24,0,0,0">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <CheckBox Name="contactChk" 
                           IsChecked={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                         Path=IsSelected}"
                           Foreground="Black" Background="Black" BorderBrush="White">  
                 </CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I want to change the selectionMode property of the checkbox but its not showing any property like this? why? And what I do.

Comment: Not the CheckBox, but the ListBox has that property, you should set it in your XAML file, like this: <ListBox x:Name="ContactResultsData" SelectionMode="Multiple" ...

Comment: And you may have to Bind the CheckBoxes' IsChecked property in the ItemTemplate to the containing ListBoxItem's IsSelected property.

Comment: But after changing SelectionMode="Multiple" It gets me error below The name 'ContactResultsData' does not exist in the current context. where I use listbox name i.e `ContactResultsData`.why?

Comment: Did you keep the x:Name="ContactResultsData" part? Maybe there is a typo, and the name of the control is misspelled...

Comment: how do you add `RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor` in the checkbox `IsChecked` binding because in the `RelativeSource Mode=` I have only values `Self` and `TemplatedParent`. So How I add `RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor`

Comment: Well, to be honest I am not familiar with winRT's xaml format, it's available in WPF, but you can use TemplatedParent, as it should be the ListBoxItem element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54535/discussion-between-user88-and-qqbenq).